# Way to check if web host supports XSLT stylesheet transformation?

Tags: php, xslt

I have a web page that uses xslt stylesheet, however it seems that it is not working properly. 
I have moved all the files from my previous web server (working) to a new one but it does not work.

My question: is there a simple way to check if there is a XSLT support?

Comment: If the browser has Javascript then XSLT will work. Perhaps you have hard coded paths in the various files.

Comment: How do you use them? Because you add the php tag, so I'm wondering ..

Comment: @EdHeal: does it even need JavaScript?

Comment: @Eric - Misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.php

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

Open in browser, search for XSLT

or

`php -i | grep xslt` in command line